# "ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible", using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science, boxplot

```
data = {'continent': ['Asia', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'North America', 'South America', 'Australia'],
       'population_density': [150, 44, 72, 22, 25, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
plt.boxplot(df['population_density'], labels=df['continent'])
plt.title('Population Densities by Continent')
plt.ylabel('Population Density')
```

my code is above. when I run it, I get the error "ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible", but idk why, there are 6 labels for 6 data points.

The condition of my question is "There must be six columns in a single boxplot area, as there are six continents".

Comment: Did you mean `bar graph` instead of `boxplot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Population densities are usually graphed in a **bar graph**. [`Here`](https://gpres.weebly.com/displaying-and-interpreting-population-data.html) is a quote that supports the statement:

> Bar graphs probably the most versatile way of displaying population
> data. They are often used to show population growth over time but they
> can also show things such as the relative proportions of different
> groups in the society or they may be used to compare populations of
> different places.

To make the bar graph, you **need to change** this line in your code:

```
plt.boxplot(df['population_density'], labels=df['continent'])
```

To this:

```
plt.bar(df['continent'], df['population_density'])
```

This is the resulting graph after running `plt.show()`:

[image: bar_graph]

If you **really want** to use a `box plot`, you can replace this:

```
plt.boxplot(df['population_density'], labels=df['continent'])
```

With this:

```
df.boxplot(by='continent')
```

This is the resulting graph after running `plt.show()`:

[image: box_plot]

As you can see, it **does not** look quite right.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. however, this is a homework question and a boxplot is a must. What should I change if I want to do it as a boxplot?

Comment: That is strange that a `boxplot` is a must. It just doesn't look right. I have edited my question to include the `boxplot` solution.